# Can't execute svn.exe in batch file called by asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, svn

I tried to execute `svn update` command through .NET webpage (C#), my code is:

```
Process pro = new Process();
pro.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Code\Batch\RestrictedFiles.bat";
pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pro.Start();
```

Every command line in batch file can be executed successfully until executing `svn update` command. I find there is a svn.exe process in Task Manager. Is it indicated that svn has been called by .NET webpage? But this process (`svn.exe`) always exists unless I killed it manually and `svn update` command can't be executed. And no error message occurred.
However, if I double click this batch file, `svn update` command can be executed successfully very soon.

My system is Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0 and development tool is Visual Studio 2008.
Please help me out. Many thanks

Comment: You should probably check if the svn process has exited using the HasExited property. If it hasnt , sleep for few seconds and recheck

Comment: svn process is alway existed, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Use Task manager or Process Explorer to see when the process is started. You can see the start time and the PID of the process that started it. That should settle who called it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once. I just added authorisation to batch:

```
svn update --username login --password pass %source%
```

Worked for me.